# Scanner app like tool in macOS

Tags: pdf, image-processing, macos, scanning

There are many scanner apps for smartphones like Microsoft Lens, Scanner Pro, Adobe Scan, etc. They usually apply some filters to make documents clean and some rotate/straighten tools to fix skewness.

When I have a picture of some documents already in my macOS, is there a tool that can do the same job? Is the same job can be done in any app? Preview or Acrobat or anything else? Of course, I can move the picture to my smartphone and then use a scanner app, but I am looking for a direct macOS method.

Answer (score 0):

There's [Readiris](https://www.irislink.com/EN-GB/c1730/Readiris-17--the-PDF-and-OCR-solution-for-MAC-.aspx) for Mac.
It's not something I use a lot, so idk if there's anything significantly better. Mine came free with my HP MF printer. They do a 30-day trial, so you could see if it suits you.